# bootstrap and bootstrap-rtl are different in LTR mode

Tags: css, layout, bootstrap-4

I designed my user interface using [bootstrap V4.0](https://getbootstrap.com/). Now I'm going to implement right to left into my design using [bootstrap-rtl V4.0](http://bootstrap.rtlcss.com/). What I expected was that in the normal case (left to right layout) bootstrap and bootstrap-rtl have the same css layout but it seems that they are not.

*For example:*

**Bootstrap**(normal case):

```
.navbar-nav {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding-left: 0;     // ***** as you can see in bootstrap it set left padding to zero
    margin-bottom: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
```

**Bootstrap-rtl**(normal case):

```
.navbar-nav {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding-right: 0;     // ***** But in bootstrap-rtl it sets right padding to zero
    margin-bottom: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
```

As you can see in left to right layout bootstrap sets the `left` padding to zero while bootstrap-rtl sets the `right` padding to zero.

My problem here is that shouldn't they act same as each other in left to right layout? or it is a normal behavior and I am missing some thing here.

Comment: @MrLister no, my problem is that, when my layout is in LTR mode(and not in RTL mode) I expect that the bootstrap-rtl act same as simple bootstrap and don't change my layout.

Comment: @MrLister In fact I expect it to affect my layout only when I add `dir="rtl"` to my layout and without this attribute, my layout should be exact the same as when I am using the bootstrap.

Comment: @MrLister That is the behavior that I remember from bootstrap V3. and bootstrap-rtl V3.